# Private keys in keystore. Which one is used while handshaking?

Tags: ssl, https, cer, handshaking

I am creating adapter for work with web-service, using proxy and ssl connection, and Have one problem with understanding Handshaking mechanism. I will explain one example.

My actions:

1. Make server. Create private key with keytool. create `.cer` file for it.
2. Make client. Create same for him.
3. Exchange `.cer` with each other, import in keystores other side's certificate.
4. Create connection. Ok. Everything is ok.
5. In server's keystore I gen new private key.

**Question**: which `pr_key` do server use for handshaking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one that has a corresponding private key.

Exporting a certificate to be used in the peer's *trust* store doesn't export the private key. So in fact there is only one to choose from: the one that corresponds to the certificate that was generated from it.

Comment: 2 stages: 1) handshake, 2) the session after that. So When are pr_key and certificate are used? While handshaking what is format of first message used for that?

Comment: In my mind - answer is "in both". What if client'll not send to server his client_pub.cer?

Comment: The certificate is sent to the peer during the handshake. The SSL handshake messages are defined in [RFC 2246](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2246.txt), although why you think you need to know them is another question. If the server asks for the client certificate and the client doesn't send it (a) it will be because the client doesn't have one or isn't properly configured, and (b) the server may or may not close the connection depending on whether it is set to 'request' or 'require' the client's certificate.